# CoreData: Efficiently fetch some before & after objects for a particular object

Tags: ios, core-data

Large data sets have been stored in the Core data local storage. I have search functionality in my app. Based on user search, a list is generated. Users can select items from the list. After selection, a new list is generated & displayed in another page. Newly generated list will contain object that the user selected & some other objects that are just before & after of the selected objects. **Every object has time property & time property should be used for ordering the objects.**  How can i fetch efficiently before & after objects for a particular selected/target object. In the local storage, there could be some data which might have same time interval.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does "some objects" mean here, is it a fixed number of objects or a more dynamic limit and if so what (how) decides the number of objects?

Comment: It's a fixed number - 10. For a particular object, need to fetch 10 before objects & 10 after objects .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a single answer for this since mainly it depends which gives the best performance

---

The first one is the most precise one but it requires two fetch request and a fetch request is costly:

Simply create two fetch requests to fetch 10 before and 10 after,

Before

```
request.fetchLimit = 11 
NSPredicate(format: "%K <= %@", #keyPath(timestamp), selectedTimestamp)
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SomeEntity.timestamp, ascending: false)
```

and after

```
request.fetchLimit = 10
NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@", #keyPath(timestamp), selectedTimestamp)
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SomeEntity.timestamp, ascending: true)
```

This will give you 10 before the selected object (`selectedTimestamp`) and 10 after, notice that = is used in only one predicate to not include duplicates. You can of course swap the place of the equal sign. I did set the firs fetch limit to 11 since it will include the selected object but a better solution is to create a compound predicate where you exclude the already selected object.

If you have a lot of objects with duplicate timestamps it will be random which 10 gets returned

---

The other solution could be used if the timestamps of the objects are roughly evenly distributed because then you could fetch based on a time interval and setting the fetch limit to a higher but still relatively small number like 100 and then extract two arrays from the result set in a simple manner based on the selected timestamp.

This way you only need one fetch request and the rest of the work should be fast

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution will work if num of objects with same timestamps is not much. Let's say there is so many objects with same timestamps. Then how can we do that?

Comment: It's really up to you to decide what to do if you only want to display 20 out of a large number of objects with the same timestamp.